# saving checkbox state on reload

Tags: php, jquery, html, session

how do i save checkbox state through sessions? i'm using this jquery code to toggle the options:

```
$('div.check input:checkbox').bind('change',function(){
    $('#'+this.id+'txt').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

but when i reload, the checkboxes are back to their default state. i know i'd have to use sessions, but how do i make the checkbox state persist using sessions in php?

html:

```
<div class="check">
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Name" id="name" checked /> <label for="name">Name</label></p>  
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Reference " id="reference" checked /> <label for="reference">Reference</label></p>
    </div>

    <div id="nametxt"> Show Name TEXT </div>
    <div id="reftxt"> Show Ref TEXT </div>
```

Comment: It might be easier to store the state of the checkboxes in [`localStorage`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localstorage) for browsers that support it or using `document.cookie`

Comment: "but when I reload..." - Are you trying to maintain state on a page refresh, before having submitted the form back to the server?!

Comment: @w3d, there is no form. just two checkboxes which display data. if the checkbox is unchecked, then it should hide the corresponding data and this state should persist, till it is checked again by the user or the user closes the browser or logs out.

Comment: FYI, you do not need to include [keywords] in the question title.  That's what tags are for.

Comment: @fusion If there is no actual form (being submitted) then this is purely a JavaScript (JQuery) and Cookie question, not PHP or (PHP) Sessions. You will need to use Cookies to maintain state.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Purely in JavaScript supporting `localStorage` if available, otherwise using `document.cookie`.

```
function getStorage(key_prefix) {
    // this function will return us an object with a "set" and "get" method
    // using either localStorage if available, or defaulting to document.cookie
    if (window.localStorage) {
      // use localStorage:
      return {
        set: function(id, data) {
          localStorage.setItem(key_prefix+id, data);
        },
        get: function(id) {
          return localStorage.getItem(key_prefix+id);
        }
      };
    } else {
      // use document.cookie:
      return {
         set: function(id, data) {
           document.cookie = key_prefix+id+'='+encodeURIComponent(data);
         },
         get: function(id, data) {
           var cookies = document.cookie, parsed = {};
           cookies.replace(/([^=]+)=([^;]*);?\s*/g, function(whole, key, value) {
              parsed[key] = decodeURIComponent(value);
           });
           return parsed[key_prefix+id];
         }
       };
     }
  }

jQuery(function($) {
  // a key prefix is used for the cookie/storage
  var storedData = getStorage('com_mysite_checkboxes_'); 

  $('div.check input:checkbox').bind('change',function(){
    $('#'+this.id+'txt').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
    // save the data on change
    storedData.set(this.id, $(this).is(':checked')?'checked':'not');
  }).each(function() {
    // on load, set the value to what we read from storage:
    var val = storedData.get(this.id);
    if (val == 'checked') $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
    if (val == 'not') $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    if (val) $(this).trigger('change');
  });

});
```

[jsFiddle demo available](http://www.jsfiddle.net/TzPW9/1/) -- Click some checkboxes, then "Run" the script again!

Comment: thank you! the demo works wonderfully, and in my project the checkbox state persists, but the corresponding data still displays on pageload, even if the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: @fusion - might be something else entirely in a different section of code, can you post a link to the actual page, I can try to firebug it for you.

Comment: @gnarf, thanks, but the project is not yet online. i tried to firebug it too, it doesn't throw any error as such. the only line in the above code that i changed was this `$('#ab_'+this.id).toggle($(this).is(':checked'));` . could it be because of this id change?

Comment: put a breakpoint on that line / the `trigger('change');` line and see if it's being run

Comment: did that, it executes that line. funny thing is that when i put the breakpoint and executed it, it works as it should . .but without the breakpoint, it doesn't -ie, it displays the text if the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: And what is the best way to remove data about checkbox statuses from storage?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but you need to make some change- off course it will work if you submit through form or JQuery with same parameter name (here name_txt and ref_txt).

give checkbox input a name

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['name_txt']))
    $name_text = $_REQUEST['name_txt'];
if(isset($_REQUEST['ref_txt']))
    $ref_text = $_REQUEST['ref_txt'];
    ?>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name = "name_txt" value="Name" id="name" <?php echo ($name_text == 'Name' || !isset($name_text))?'checked':'';?> /> 
    <label for="name">Name</label></p>  
    <p><input type="checkbox" name = "ref_txt" value="Reference " id="reference" <?php echo ($ref_text == 'Reference' || !isset($ref_text))?'checked':'';?> /> <label for="reference">Reference</label></p>
```

Comment: somehow doesn't work. also i want the default value to be checked, so that the text is shown. but with this code, it shows the code even if the code is unchecked [default] on pageload.

Comment: can you show your php script plz? are you submitting input through form or JQuery? how? please make it clear.

Answer (score -1):

If it's not something that you need to save in the database I recommend using cookies instead of sessions. You can use the easy jQuery **[cookies plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie)**.

Comment: how would i store the checkbox state in the cookie. any help would be appreciated.