# checkbox state should retain state to hide/unhide text on pageload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, checkbox

as a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313595/saving-checkbox-state-on-reload), while the checkbox value is stored on pageload, the text is displayed on pageload, even if the checkbox is unchecked. the text should hide/display only if the user has  unchecked/checked the checkbox, throughout the session or till he closes the browser.

js code which stores the checkbox state:

```
function getStorage(key_prefix) {
    // this function will return us an object with a "set" and "get" method
    // using either localStorage if available, or defaulting to document.cookie
    if (window.localStorage) {
      // use localStorage:
      return {
        set: function(id, data) {
          localStorage.setItem(key_prefix+id, data);
        },
        get: function(id) {
          return localStorage.getItem(key_prefix+id);
        }
      };
    } else {
      // use document.cookie:
      return {
         set: function(id, data) {
           document.cookie = key_prefix+id+'='+encodeURIComponent(data);
         },
         get: function(id, data) {
           var cookies = document.cookie, parsed = {};
           cookies.replace(/([^=]+)=([^;]*);?\s*/g, function(whole, key, value) {
              parsed[key] = decodeURIComponent(value);
           });
           return parsed[key_prefix+id];
         }
       };
     }
  }

jQuery(function($) {
  // a key prefix is used for the cookie/storage
  var storedData = getStorage('com_mysite_checkboxes_'); 

  $('div.check input:checkbox').bind('change',function(){
    $('#ab_'+this.id).toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
    // save the data on change
    storedData.set(this.id, $(this).is(':checked')?'checked':'not');
  }).each(function() {
    // on load, set the value to what we read from storage:
    var val = storedData.get(this.id);
    if (val == 'checked') $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
    if (val == 'not') $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    if (val) $(this).trigger('change');
  });

});
```

this ^code should work, but it while it retains the state of the checkbox, it doesn't for the text. **is it because the text is being called from a php page?**

html:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#bquote").load("quotes_in.php");     
    });


.. ...

<div class="check">
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Name" id="name" checked /> <label for="name">Name</label></p>  
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Reference " id="reference" checked /> <label for="reference">Reference</label></p>
    </div>

.. ...

    <blockquote id="bquote">
        &nbsp;  
    </blockquote>
```

php:

```
public function formatQuotes($row)
{

    return "<p id=\"ab_name\">" . $this->h($row['cName']) . "</p><br />"
    . "<p id=\"ab_reference\">" . $this->h($row['vReference']) . "</p>"; 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger the `change()` event on document ready after the `p` elements are generated.

**Edit:**

If placing the change trigger after the `.load()` call does not work, then that is probably due to the ajax request not being completed yet at the point of triggering. This can be solved by using `callback` parameter of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Therefore, the code should look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bquote").load("quotes_in.php", function() {
        // create the P elements
        // trigger the change() event
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response. so i should insert the code in `jQuery(function($)` to `$(document).ready(function()`?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Just make sure that it's after `$("#bquote").load("quotes_in.php")`.

Comment: doesn't work. it retains the checkbox state, but still displays the text on pageload regardless of whether the checkbox is checked or not.