# How to display "selected radio button" after refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

After refresh the page, the user selected radio button is missing.
How can I always display the user's "selected radio button" even I had refresh the page?

```
<input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="" id="all" checked />
```

radio with checked is not suitable, because it will always display the default radio button.

Below is my code:-

```
<form name="myfrm" id="myfrm" action="" method="post">
    <input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="" id="all" />
    <label>All Languages</label>
    <input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="" id="english" />
    <label>English</label>
</form>
```

Comment: You want to maintain the selected radio button on refresh or on postback bcoz refresh is just like u send a request to a page so it will display by default selected radio button that u set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [saving checkbox state on reload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313595/saving-checkbox-state-on-reload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should conform to standards and give a value to every attribute. That means you need checked="checked"

```
<input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="" id="all" checked="checked" />
```

And in case you were asking how to stick to what was selected previously: AFAIK, it is not possible with plain HTML. You need to bind a Javascript event that submits the selected radio button to your server and a dynamically generated page (by PHP, Python, whatever) that puts the 'checked="checked" to the radio button that was submitted as checked.

**EDIT:**

As I see it, submitting the currently selected radio button to the server and generating your page dynamically might be overkill.

Comment: what?????? it will always show that checkbox as checked irrespective of it's checked by user or not...first read the question, then answer...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question at first.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is something you'd want. But a thing that comes up to mind is the HTML5 Web Storage functionality.With that feature you can store data on the computer of the user.

So whenever a user changes an input field you can create a javascript call that stores the value into the localstorage:

```
localStorage.setItem(“inputName”, “value”);
```

Then when you load the page, you see if any of these values are stored and then fill them in.

Answer (score 0):

i think this discussion is going to help you...though this discussion is about saving state of checkbox, but you can modify that code according to your need..hope this helps to you!!!

[**Save state of inputElement**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313595/saving-checkbox-state-on-reload)

Comment: Actually, this would be my first time  posting question on stackoverflow.com. Never expect I will get the response so fast.

Comment: Let's me figure out every suggestion and answer first. thanks.