# How do you save a Checkbox State in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, save, local-storage

I'm designing a web app for Document Managers, and there is a 'settings' page, where the user sees a pair of checkboxes formatted to look like the iphone toggle buttons. they work and all, but whenever the user leaves the website or refreshes the page the state of those buttons is reset back to the default. is there a way to save the state of them using *localStorage* or do i need to use *cookies*? **EDIT** in the JavaScript file (code shown below) there are two functions, one called *saveSettings* and the other *loadSettings*, but if i have to do it all in one function then please tell me. **END OF EDIT** any help at all would be greatly appreciates. so far i have;

```
localStorage.CheckboxName = $('#CheckboxName').val();
```

to save the checkbox to *localStorage* and;

```
$('#CheckboxName').val(localStorage.CheckboxName);
```

but it won't save. Am i doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

here's the HTML code of the two checkboxes;

```
<li style = 'color: #FFFFFF;'>Notifications<span class = 'toggle'><input type = 'checkbox' class = 'toggle' name = 'notifications' id = 'notifications' /></span></li>
<li style = 'color: #FFFFFF;'>Preview<span class = 'toggle'><input type = 'checkbox' class = 'toggle' name = 'preview' id = 'preview' checked = "true" /></span></li>
```

**END OF EDIT**

Any help would be amazing, thanks in advance x

Comment: Are you using jQuery local storage or HTML5 local storage??

Comment: ok.. what has that to do with the checkboxes? no offense, i just don't see the relevance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I've always believed that it was like this :

```
window.localStorage.setItem('CheckboxName', $('#CheckboxName').val());

$('#CheckboxName').val(window.localStorage.getItem('CheckboxName'));
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but where you put 'CheckboxName' - is that not supposed to have a # infront of it? plus it doesn't work for me

Comment: ok...that makes sense. but i don't want an alert box i wanted it to just stay either checked or not when the user revisits the page or website.

Comment: the line $('#test')[0].checked = $.parseJSON(window.localStorage.getItem('a')); do the job. The alert box is just to control ... (You can delete it).

Plus, you can test on http://jsfiddle.net/Bc5xf/5/ ... check the box, click on store and reload the jsfiddle page.

Comment: oh ok. you mean the line attached to the 'store' button? and in my .js file i have two functions; saveSettings and loadSettings. would i put it into save- or loadSettings?

Comment: saveSettings =  window.localStorage.setItem('a', JSON.stringify($('#CheckboxName')[0].checked));

||||||| loadSettings = $('#CheckboxName')[0].checked = $.parseJSON(window.localStorage.getItem('a'));

Comment: ok thanks a lot. could you so the same for a selection list? like the same sort of code but to save the selected option? or should i ask a question on here regarding it?

Comment: oh and where you put 'a', my button is an input button and not a, 'a' class. do i substitute 'a' with 'input' or does it mean something else?

Comment: a is just the variable name inside the localstorage ... you can call it like you want. For a selection list you need to create a new question on stackoverflow. Don't forget  on this thread to check the answer who help you the more (and eventualy upvote it)

Comment: ok thanks. and i would upvote but i'm one of those point-things short of being able to do that :S thanks a lot for your help x

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17881/discussion-between-my-boon-and-megansime)

Comment: hi sorry to keep bothering you but i need help, the code you gave me doesn't work - is there any other way i could code it? here's the link to my .js file (the whole thing - it's called save.js), and the index.html is the code for the web page. the 'settings' div is at the bottom of index.html; https://www.dropbox.com/home#!/home/Public/Project

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

$("#CheckboxName").is(':checked')?'checked':'not' and save the output, seems to be what is suggested here:
[How to use local storage to retain checkbox states for filtering items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096745/how-to-use-local-storage-to-retain-checkbox-states-for-filtering-items)

Comment: ok thanks. em the link you sent me didn't particularly help in my case. i have two functions to hold and load the settings saved on the settings page - do you know how to split the function up? i can't work it out.

Answer (score 0):

To store an Item just remember that the store only holds strings.

Eg.

```
var val = $('#CheckboxName').val();
window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(val));
```

So when you read the value back you need to deserialize the string.

```
var str = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
var obj = $.parseJSON(str);
```

Or you could just do string comparison whatever suites your needs better in your case what I would do is store an object of id value pairs in one storage key and deserialize them all to work with proper object

Eg.

```
var val = {
    CheckboxName1: true,
    CheckboxName2: false,
    CheckboxName3: false, // ect....
};
window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(val));
```

Comment: thanks a lot but the lat block of code you gave me doesn't make much sense. i have two checkboxes - one called 'notifications' and the other 'preview', how would i code those into the second code you gave me? i tried the first block of code but it didn't work.